# Chrome - avoid displaying start-up popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am starting Chrome with the following command:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/data --app=http://greensock.com/gsap
```

As I am running this in a docker container, the chrome profile will not exist. 
If /data is empty, then the following popup is displayed. How can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. 
--no-first-run does the job.

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-first-run

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/data --no-first-run http:/www.google.com
```

To test, remove the /data first, like:

```
rm -R /data && google-chrome --user-data-dir=/data --no-first-run http:/www.google.com
```